# What exactly is the error here ? is it with the return statement?

Tags: python

Make sure that the_flying_circus() returns True

```
def the_flying_circus(): 
    if 45 > 34 and ( 49 == 7**2 ) :    
       Print ("nandy is sweet")
       Return (True)

    elif 73 >= 70+3 or ( 12 < 24  ): # an elif after if 
       Print ("raju is bad")
       Return (True) # the return is right ?
    else:
       Print ("go back to school")

    # codeacademy says there is an error but is not telling what it is
```

Comment: Don't capitalize `print` or `return`

Comment: If you had tried to *run* the code, the answer would have been obvious.

Comment: If the task is "Make sure that the_flying_circus() returns True" a `return True` as the first line of the function would have been enough.

Answer (score 2):

Your P in print is capital and your R in return is capital. It should be print and return

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't use capitals in the "print" and "return" statements, the code runs fine.

```
def the_flying_circus(): 
    if 45 > 34 and ( 49 == 7**2 ) :    
       print ("nandy is sweet")
       return (True)

    elif 73 >= 70+3 or ( 12 < 24  ): # an elif after if 
       print ("raju is bad")
       return (True) # the return is right ?
   else:
       print ("go back to school")
```